# Why I get name 'url_link' is not defined error?

Tags: python

I have this part of code want to compare two files xls and json in json I have empty string and empty cell in xls == naan

```
if row["URL Link"] == "nan":
    global url_link
    url_link = ''

assert_equal_values(str(item["urlLink"]), url_link, "URL Link is not match!")
```

got this error name

> url_link is not defined

if I remove `global`  then I got

> local variable 'url_link' referenced before assignment

```
if row["URL Link"] == "nan":
    url_link = ''
```

Comment: Apparently the condition in `if` was false, so `url_link=''` was not executed.

Comment: no cus when I print url_lin i got empty string

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution row["URL Link"] need to be a string 
so added str(row["URL Link"])